# Como saber se um cadastro ja foi feito no banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql, query

Como faço para verificar se determinado id foi cadastrado no banco, e se não tiver cadastrado usar uma query de insert e se já estiver cadastrado usar uma query de update ?

Comment: vc pode definir algum campo como unique quando o insert falhar por violara restrição do unique, faça um update;

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro selecione a ID que deseja cadastrar e transforme-a em uma variável.

Depois crie uma query, e depois cheque os resultados:

```
SELECT id FROM suaTabela WHERE id=$id

if ($con->num_rows == 1) {

//código afirmando que já existe uma id cadastrada

}
else if ($con->num_rows == 0) {

//codigo afirmando que nenhuma id foi cadastrada

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não detalhou muito bem o que quer, mas vou tentar criar um exemplo. Vamos supor que seja um produto, e você receba o nome e o id dele por uma função:

```
function trataProduto($conexao, $nomeProduto, $idProduto){
    //Verifica se o produto já existe (pelo id)
    $sql_verifica = "SELECT * FROM lista_de_produtos WHERE produto_id = $idProduto";
    $r = mysqli_query($con, $sql_verifica) ord die(mysqli_error());
    if(mysqli_num_rows($r) >= 1){
        //Faz a query para editar
    }
    else{
        //Faz a query para dar INSERT
    }
}
```

Espero que tenha ajudado, se não for esse o problema, comenta ai!